# What is the advantage and disadvantage of developing Hybrid App using Apache Cordova in Visual Studio Community

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

We are going to develop a Mobile Application for all platform, This Mobile Application includes main concept as messaging,notes,reading a book,blogs,sharing on facebook, tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Advantages**:

- Easy to write code in Visual studio due to context aware help
- Code completion for JavaScript, CSS, HTML
- Easy to debug in browsers like Chrome is best
- Check on simulators (on windows only for Windows mobile, Blackberry, and even can check on Android)

**Disadvantages**:

- Can not test all devices or simulators like iOS
- Limited Command Line support options
- Little support for Visually designing a page UI

Few simulators that I use on VS.
http://www.asp.net/mobile/device-simulators

also have a [look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f38yc3w5(v=vs.85).aspx):

Comment: Is there any problem on phone performance.

Comment: On which device? I tested on Android, iPhone, Blackberry there is no issue. Its just an IDE and its all depends on your code.

Comment: Could you suggest some sample framework for developing the above concept.

Comment: sure, but didn't get your idea of framework, please clarify :)

Comment: like coding4fun,windows phone toolkit,telerik. We are going to develop a authendicated player for school and it's have lots of boos with communicating students to teacher, take notes.

Comment: Use Cordova with JQuery Mobile. Both are free and open source with lots of FREE resources, tutorials, plugins, demos and off course code samples. For cordova you need JavaScript, CSS, HTML skills. I hope you are developing this for students. But if you want your students to learn some coding or tool as well then I recommend MIT APP Inventor...very easy tool specially for student to get Mobile programmings understanding and skills.

Comment: Now I am starting my mobile development, But there is again one problem, When I build my app in IOS ,I followed the stepts as install sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote --user=$USER, It succes, but next step vs-mda-remote generateClientCert is failed through message as iMac-KQ:~ test$ vs-mda-remote generateClientCert
vs-mda-remote
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
0.2.5

One or both of required CA files /Users/test/remote-builds/certs/ca-key.pem and /Users/test/remote-builds/certs/ca-cert.pem not found.